# How to avoid "yum lock" hassle?

Tags: centos, yum

I often encounter the "Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit..." message when trying to install an app and I have to kill yum manually.  How can I avoid that? Is there any simple method to unlock yum?

It seems that only one instance of yum can be running. Is it the same with other package mangers (apt-get, pacman)?

Comment: In my case, I was connected to a server via VPN. Once I ran `sudo yum -y update`, all packages were getting updated, along with open-VPN. Once open-VPN package got updated, I was disconnected from the VPN. I log back in, try the yum update again and it says the same thing.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think it is caused by PackageKit. You have to check for PackageKit and disable it (I assume it is CentOS 7 with `systemctl`, otherwise you can use `service` and `chkconfig`) (as mentioned in comments, the service name is `packagekit` not `packagekitd`):

```
systemctl stop packagekit
systemctl disable packagekit
```

Another approach (On CentOS/RHEL 6, Fedora 19 or earlier) is to open `/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/refresh-packagekit.conf` with a text editor, and change `enabled=1` to `enabled=0`.

Or you can completely remove it:

```
yum remove PackageKit
```

Comment: It is called `packagekit.service` on my Centos 7

Comment: In my case, I simply ran *systemctl stop packagekit* and then the yum lock was freed.

Comment: I moved to docker and cannot verify this fix, for the time being I mark this as an answer. thanks.

Answer (score 12):

do the following to solve the problem:

```
cd /var/run
rm -f yum.pid
```

you could also update your yum afterward

```
yum -y update
```

Comment: This is fighting symptoms and not fixing the real cause.

Comment: Yikes. It's hard to recommend this under any circumstances, because that `.pid` file is there for a reason. The same "Another app is currently holding the yum lock" message the original poster mentioned will also tell you the PID of the running process holding the lock. At the very least, you'd want to `kill` or `kill -HUP` that process to give it a chance to _try_ to finish what it's doing, lest you risk corrupting YUM's internal state.

Answer (score 6):

You can unlock yum by following two simple steps,

1) Run `ps aux | grep yum` to see which process is locking yum.
2) `kill <process_id>` to kill the process.

Again run `ps aux | grep yum` to see if the process is killed or not. Yum will be unlocked after killing the process.

Comment: this "works" but is probably bad practice

Comment: This works in select circumstances. I have encountered a situation where systemd restarts the packagekit process before I can start my own yum command. And yes, also it is probably bad practice to kill the PID instead of gracefully telling packagekit to not run.

Comment: It can also solve problems like `[4]+  Stopped <THE COMMAND>`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was connected to a server via VPN (open VPN). Once I ran `sudo yum -y update`, all packages were getting updated, along with open-VPN. Once open-VPN package got updated, I was disconnected from the VPN. I logged back in, tried the yum update again and it said another process is holding the yum lock.

I checked with `ps ax | grep yum` and the old process was still running. I waited for 5 min for it to "finish", but the process just kept running. Then I thought I could "pull the trigger" with kill, so I ran

`kill <PID of the yum update process>`

That didn't kill the process. Tried that a few more times, and still no success.

Finally I had to really pull the plug on it, by running:

`kill -9 <PID of the yum update process>`

Tried yum update again, but same issue. I then ran:

`rm -f /var/run/yum.pid`

and then tried update and got this output:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.sigmanet.com
 * epel: mirror.sjc02.svwh.net
 * extras: mirrors.vpsie.com
 * updates: mirror.pac-12.org
No Packages marked for Update
```

Believe everything is good, but I didn't like pulling the plug on so many things!

Answer (score 1):

`systemctl disable packagekit` **is not enough**.  packagekit will be running upon reboot.  Use the `mask` command instead of the `disable` command.

```
[root@localhost yum.repos.d]# systemctl mask packagekit
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/packagekit.service to /dev/null.
```

Then upon reboot you will see ...

```
[sri@localhost ~]$ systemctl status packagekit
● packagekit.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Comment: Here's a good discussion about _why_ that's the case: https://askubuntu.com/questions/816285/what-is-the-difference-between-systemctl-mask-and-systemctl-disable

Answer (score 0):

uninstalling PackageKit will also remove the software gui.
instead do this, this has been effective for me with RHEL >= 7.6.

create **/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/refresh-packagekit.conf**

```
[main]
enabled=0
```